# Mapping of a number to two nearest multiples of 2, starting at a specific value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I'm trying to come up with a function/mapping from a given number `n`, to two numbers `lo` and `hi`. Both `lo` and `hi` are of some multiple of 2, starting from the value 6.25. Both `lo` and `hi` also have the property that `lo <= n < hi`.

Essentially `lo` and `hi` are the two nearest values to `n`, formed from `6.25 * (2^x)` where `x` is unknown.

It can be assumed that `n >= 6.25`.

Some examples are:

```
n = 10  -> [6.25, 12.5]
n = 12  -> [6.25, 12.5]
n = 13  -> [12.5, 25]
n = 25  -> [25, 50]
n = 40  -> [25, 50]
n = 50  -> [50, 100]
n = 300 -> [200, 400]
n = 400 -> [400, 800]
n = 413 -> [400, 800]
n = 500 -> [400, 800]
```

This is trivial to write as a loop in JavaScript for example:

```
const nearest = n => {
  let lo = 6.25;
  let hi = lo * 2;

  while (n >= hi) {
    lo *= 2;
    hi *= 2;
  }

  return [lo, hi];
}
```

But ideally i'd rather do it in a 'mathy' way and not use loops. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function nearest(n) {
    let exponent = Math.floor(Math.log2(n/6.25));
    let lo = Math.pow(2, exponent) * 6.25;
    let hi = lo * 2;

    return [lo, hi];
}
```

The log will give you the exponent for the `lo` value to be just under `n`. Note that you have to "normalize" the input by dividing (and later multiplying) by your factor 6.25.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is what you need. FYI `Math.log2` is [not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log2), so you can include a polyfill.

```js
// Polyfill
if (!Math.log2) {
    Math.log2 = function(x) {
      return Math.log(x) * Math.LOG2E;
    };
}

function mapValue(value) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.log2(value / 6.25));
    
    var lo = 6.25 * Math.pow(2, x);
    var hi = lo * 2;
    
    return [lo, hi];
}

console.log([10, 12, 13, 25, 40, 50, 300, 400, 413, 500].map(mapValue));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
arr = [10, 12, 13, 25, 40, 50, 300, 400, 413, 500];

arr.forEach(a => {
  spanningRange = Math.max(2 ** Math.floor((Math.log(a / 100) / Math.log(2))) * 100, 6.25);
  console.log(`${a} -> [${spanningRange}, ${spanningRange * 2}]`)
});
```

but note that [`**` is part of ES7 but is ok in Google Chrome v79 and many modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=Exponentiation%20operator).